# Building data base, read method

Tags: c++

Can anyone why this code does not work? 
It says that this operator does not exists or something like that.
Please help me

```
void Account::read_rec()
{
    std::ifstream infile;
    infile.open("record.bank", std::ios::binary);
    if (!infile)
    {
        std::cout << "[Error] File Not Found!" << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "\n***** Data from file *****" << std::endl;

    while (!infile.eof())
    {
        if (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this) > 0))
        {
            show_data();
        }
    }
    infile.close();
}
```

Comment: "Something like that"? Why not show us the actual message?

Comment: **Recommended reading:** [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/560648)

Comment: Also you have to be really careful if you want to serialise/deserialise in a byte-by-byte way like this. There are stringent constraints. Usually we create more sophisticated serialisation/deserialisation logic...

Answer (score 2):

```
if (infile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(this), sizeof(*this) > 0))
//                                                          ^   ^
//                                                          A   B
```

The end of the `read` function call should be at A, not at B.

You put the bracket in the wrong place.

There is no `read(char*, bool)` function ;)